# How to select drop down list when object/value is always changeable in protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Anyone can help me how to call the drop down list for protractor? The highlighted object is not fixed value/object. Means it always changed. The below code is not working for me:

```
element(by.model('residential')).$('[value="object:353"]').click();
```

AngularJS as per below:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched" ng-model="residential" id="ResidentStatus" ng-options="status as status.Name for status in residentialStatus" style="">
  <option value="" class="" selected="selected">Please Select Resident Status option label="Malaysian" value="object:353">Malaysian</option>
  <option label="Non-Malaysian" value="object:354">Non-Malaysian</option>
</select>
```

I hope someone can give an idea for me. thanks all

Comment: Have you tried the ID? That doesn't seem random. Please list the different things you have tried and the results of each.. error messages, etc. "Not working" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: i have tried this and not working.

var malaysian = element(by.cssContainingText('Malaysian', 'Malaysian'));
  malaysian.click();

this one is working. but sometimes it will the run will effect other element that cause failed.

var malaysian = element(by.css('option[label="Malaysian"]'));

Answer (score 0):

You can use the label, it looks like is not changeable:

```
element(by.css('option[label="Malaysian"]'))

element(by.css('option[label="Non-Malaysian"]'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Sanja Paskova. This is works for me. 
var malaysian = element(by.css('option[label="Malaysian"]'));

But when I run second time, it affects other as well and i got this message throw such as " no element found for other locator" .

Comment: How do you mean affects other as well? It selects Non-Malaysian when you want to select Malaysian?

Comment: I mean affect other specs. But now its working without failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

page object:

```
 get dropDown(){ return element(by.cssContainingText('label','Malaysian'));},
```

Spec class:

```
   expect(page.dropDown.getText()).toEqual("Malaysian");
```